# What is the difference between pool.imap_unordered() and pool.apply_async()?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

What is the difference between `pool.imap_unordered()` and `pool.apply_async()`?

When `pool.imap_unordered()` is preferred over `pool.apply_async()` or vice versa?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? `imap_unordered` *maps* a function over an iterable.

Comment: When you provide the input in an iterator, it acts like apply_asyc(), I mean takes the input one by one, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of calling `pool.apply_async(f, (1, 2, 3, 4))` is that `f(1, 2, 3, 4)` will be called in some thread.  The value returned by `apply_async` is an `AsyncResult` which you can use to wait on the result.

The result of calling `pool.imap_unordered(f, (1, 2, 3, 4))` is an iterator.  It returns the results of `f(1)`, `f(2)`, `f(3)` and `f(4)` is an unspecified order.

Comment: When you have big data (B), you can read them one by one (b), process each data r=p(b) and accumulate each result (r) in big result R+=r. Which one is better?

Comment: You sound like you're describing what `imap_unordered` is for.  If you have a really large amount of data, you might want to consider some mapreduce framework which can also handle concurrent summing.

Comment: The problem is that I'm repeating the same procedure for multiple times, it is working for several times and then it is getting stuck. Only one process (main process) is remaining in S mode. Have a look please.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65375778/best-practice-for-using-python-pool-apply-async-with-callback-function                                                                     
Please notice that this is a very simplified version. Assume that I repeat it for several times.

Comment: Can you give example for "mapreduce framework which can also handle concurrent summing. "?